# Validação de dados submetidos pelo formulário

Tags: php, html

Estou fazendo a validação de um formulário e enfrento um problema que não consigo resolver. Primeiro, faço um *foreach* e verifico se há algum `$_POST` vazio, caso haja, executa: `$error[$key] = "*";`. Depois, abaixo do *input*, verifico se o usuário clicou no *submit* e se a variável `$error[$key]` foi setada, caso sim, imprime `"*"; <br>`, porém, nada acontece.

*foreach*:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
   if(empty($_POST[$value])) {
      $error[$key] = "*";
      $valida = false;
   }
}
```

*input*:

```
<input type="text" class="demoInputBox" name="firstName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['firstName'])) echo $_POST['firstName']; ?>">
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and isset($error['firstName'])) echo "<label style = 'color: #ff0000'>" . $error['firstName'] . "</label>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Como você está atribuindo o `value` do `input` para `$key`, substitua o

```
if(empty($_POST[$value])) {
  ...
}
```

por

```
if(empty($_POST[$key])) {
  ...
}
```

Completinho:

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(empty($_POST[$key])) {
        $error[$key] = "*";
        $valida = false;
    }
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" class="demoInputBox" name="firstName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['firstName'])) echo $_POST['firstName']; ?>">
    <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and isset($error['firstName'])) echo "<label style = 'color: #ff0000'>" . $error['firstName'] . "</label>"; ?>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Não mudou nada, creio eu que seja que pelo fato de o $_POST ser um array, tanto faz procurar pelo key ou value, ambos são vazios

Comment: Tem certeza, cara? Fiz o teste aqui e funcionou certinho.

Comment: Eu descobri o erro, eu tava colocando o foreach depois do input... o código tá certo, eu que fui burro mesmo. Obrigado por responder e desculpa por fazer tu perder teu tempo